# Scraping the svg elements from a d3.js "block" using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, d3.js, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, localhost

This might be quite a niche question - I need to scrape the svg elements from a locally run d3.js project using python. I'm currently using the beautiful soup package and loading in my local index.html file - but obviously the svg hasn't been rendered. Would anyone know if any possible ways around this?

Comment: Use phantom.js or any other headless browser to run the javascript code, and once it's "done" extract the data from the svg. Note that the "done" is a bit tricky here, because d3's animations/rotations can be endless.

Comment: @Dekel I'd like to do it all within a python app with out any manual intervention...

Comment: where did I mention anything manual in my comment?

Comment: @Dekel ... It sounded manual. Apologies. Could I use perhaps a webdriver with Selenium and then drive my index.html with phantomjs ?

Comment: If you are using selenium with webdriver I think it's better to just use chrome/firefox and not phantom.js.

Comment: @Dekel Would you know how to read in a local .html file with Selenium?

Comment: You will need to run it under a server (apache for example, or even simple python server that will just server it under `http://127.0.0.1`).

Comment: So using something like SimpleHTTPServer. Do you think you'd have time to show me an example selenium scrape of my local index.html file for just the svg container? Assuming I'm serving it up on the generic port 8000?

Comment: I think you should start something and when you will have a problem - ask about that specifically.

Comment: @Dekel Hmmm ok. It's hard to know where to start. One final question - could I use the BeautifulSoup parser to pull down the index.html file once it's served on local host with the SVG tags rendered?

Comment: yes, you can. usually "yes/no" questions are not so good. just try and when you have a problem - ask.